# iPhone app for bitcoin

Tags: wallet

What does BitCoin suggested is the best App for iPhone?

Comment: Which company? Open-ended [recommendation questions](http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask) are not quite suited to the StackExchange format. This question might be closed if you don't explicit what your specific needs are.

Answer (score 1):

Bitcoin does not suggest anything, it is a currency and a project, not a person.

Generally, the choice of an iPhone app is limited by the factor that probably what you'd want to see the most, a wallet app, is not possible on iPhone due to Apple's restrictions.